# JPQL query for updating an object

Tags: sql, spring, database, jpql

I am trying to update a variable named endDate, which is of type LocalDate, using jpql. My query is as follow:

```
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE TeamEntity t SET t.coach.endDate = ?2 WHERE t.coach.id = ?1")
public void updateCoachEndDate(long coachId, LocalDate endDate);
```

part of TeamEntity class is as follow

```
@Entity
public class TeamEntity{

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "coach_id", nullable = true)
    private CoachEntity coach;
```

}

part of CoachEntity class is as follow

```
@Entity
public class CoachEntity{
    @Id
    private long id;
    private LocalDate endDate
}
```

When I run a test for it, it seems that it doesn't like

```
r.coach.endDate = ?2
```

and it gives me the following error

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "UPDATE Team CROSS[*] JOIN  SET END_DATE=? WHERE COACH_ID=? "; expected "., AS, SET"; SQL statement:
update team cross join  set end_date=? where coach_id=? [42001-199]
```

I just wondering if anyone know how to fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

Your descriptions don't match, i.e. I'm unsure where "staff" comes from. Anyhow:

The Hibernate documentation says:

> No join, either implicit or explicit, can be specified in a bulk HQL
>   query. Sub-queries can be used in the where-clause, where the
>   subqueries themselves may contain joins.

And you have an implicit join in there between TeamEntity and Coach.

So, the next question is, why go through the TeamEntity anyway, since you have the coachId?

```
update Coach c set c.endDate = ?2 where c.id = ?1
```

Should do the trick

Comment: Hi, sorry that was meant to be coach rather than staff. Regarding to the error, I have no idea either.I assumed that cross join is something built-in in jqpl when it wants to join Team table with Coach table.